# How to navigate to different pivot items in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a panorama page in which I have 3 buttons. I have added a pivotpage to the same project  which has 3 pivot items. When I click Button 1 in panorama page it should goto the first pivot item in pivot page and when I click button 2 in panorama page it should goto the second pivot item in pivot page. How can I achieve this navigation? Please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass a querystring to the pivot page and then, once the pivot is loaded, set the index to the relevant page. As a basic example, you can handle `button 2` like this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/myPivotPage.xaml?id=2", UriKind.Relative));
```

Then in your pivot page's `Loaded` event, you can set the jump to the index like this:

```
string pivotIndex = "";

if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("id", out pivotIndex))
{
    //-1 because the Pivot is 0-indexed, so pivot item 2 has an index of 1
    myPivot.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(pivotIndex) - 1;
}
```