# Navigate between panorama items wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, uinavigationitem, panorama-control

I just want to Know, how can I navigate between different panorama items in wp7 through c# code.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this : [navigate with Quey string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284334/how-to-navigate-to-different-pivot-items-in-wp7

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Panorama.SetValue(Panorama.SelectedItemProperty, selectedItem);
```

This might solve the issue.

Comment: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/63484.aspx 
Try your luck here, might end up finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the default item to which item u want to load for the user's view..

```
panSOS.DefaultItem = panSOS.Items[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this out, but it should work.

1. Loop through `Panorama.Items` and remove every item except for the one you want to focus on. Use a `for` loop instead of `foreach` to do this since you can't modify the collection while iterating using the latter.
2. Call `Panorama.UpdateLayout` to force the panorama to redraw itself and switch to item you want to display.
3. Add the items you removed in step 1.

Comment: There's the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622214/how-to-programatically-set-selected-panorama-item-in-wp7  which uses DefaultItem, which basically seems like what you're describing.

Comment: @willmel DefaultItem only applies when first viewing the panorama i.e it is the first panorama item that will be displayed when navigating to the page. Setting this property will not switch between panorama items.

Comment: @willmel defaultitem just changes the order of the panorama items.

Answer (score -2):

If you're panorama control is called PanoramaControl1 then you should be able to use:

```
PanoramaControl1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Where 0 is the first panorama page.

Comment: Nope, can't do that, [`Panorama.SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectedindex%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is read-only