# Need to change selected index in Panorama Item based on selection in Listview?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, panorama-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Navigate between panorama items wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233022/navigate-between-panorama-items-wp7)

I have a listview in the default PanoramaItem with other PanoramaItems Like category, favorite, settings etc. All these PanoramaItems are listed in the listview and on change in selection of listview item it should take to the corresponding PanoramaItem. But i tried to change using Panorama.selectedindex but it is readonly property. The other approach was to change defaultItem on OnNavigationTo event but since my listview is inside same Panorama hence this approach won't work. Is there some direct aproach to this?

Comment: This was discusses here already a no of time. Please check this one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233022/navigate-between-panorama-items-wp7/10240918#10240918

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the default item to which item u want to load for the user's view..

```
panSOS.DefaultItem = panSOS.Items[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your SelectionChanged event handler of the ListView, you should be able to set the DefaultItem of the Panorama to the particular item you want to view.