# Sliding Navigate Between WP>7 Pages

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, slide, navigateuri

lets say that we have 5 Xaml Pages.
Page1.xaml with the Page1.cs
Page2.xaml with the Page2.cs
Page3.xaml with the Page3.cs
Page4.xaml with the Page4.cs
Page5.xaml with the Page5.cs

and all are working separately and you can access them via Page1.xaml by tapping some icons!,
now i want to make the Navigating via sliding the Pages, so for example

if i am in Page2 and slide from right to left then then you will go to Page3, if you slide from right to left again you will go to Page4, so if now slide from left to right you will return to Page3.

This is my goal and it will be very nice to see a little part from the next and previous page in right and left of current page in order to know where i will go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your Page1 and delete others.
Add a [PanoramaPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202912(v=vs.105).aspx) to your project. I am pretty sure this is what you are looking for.
[image: Panorama page example]

To navigate to a PanoramaItem check [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284334/how-to-navigate-to-different-pivot-items-in-wp7).

By the way, you should check [PivotPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202919(v=vs.105).aspx) too.

Comment: Yes is like that i want but i do not want to delete other pages and keep one because the other pages have a lot of code that cannot be mixed with the others! Is possible to load each one when i am sliding in panorama? Thanks!

Comment: Just copy/paste you code from your pages to the new one. Do you know/use MVVM ?

Comment: Thanks man really helps, but I do not thing that is so simple as i may have textBlock1 in Page2 and the same name "textBlock1" in Page2!

Comment: So rename your control. Add a relevant name. You should read [Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx).

Comment: You have right but when i was building the app i wasn't know that can i use PivotPage, now we are talking for 50> controls all over the pages! And also variables in cs with the same name

Comment: I think you are going to have a nice time of refactoring. I do not think that I can help you more. Maybe an other user will find a solution. If my answer help you, dont forget to upvote it and mark it as "solved".

Comment: Yes i thing you solved this! but i thing i can't mark it as Solved i do not have an option like that! How can i upvoted?

Comment: You can mark as "solved" with the big white tick to the side of the answer. Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487251/sliding-navigate-between-wp7-pages/18487446#vote-accepted-18487446). And to upvote, click on the up arrow just above.

Comment: Thanks, i marked it as solved, but i do not have enough reputation to upvote it!